# Angular Testing- Can't resolve all parameters for MyOverlayRef: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular-test

I created a reusable overlay modal in angular based on the [this blogs code](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/reusable-modal-overlay-using-angular-cdk-overlay/). I have a file named `overlay-ref.ts` with code

```
export class MyOverlayRef<R = any, T = any> {
  constructor(
    public overlay: OverlayRef,
    public content: string | TemplateRef<any> | Type<any>,
    public data: T // pass data to modal i.e. FormData
  ) {}
}
```

As you can see it's not decorated with `@Injectable`, so when I use this file in my components I use it like this

```
export class CompanyContactOverlayComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(public ref: MyOverlayRef){} 
 }
```

In my component it works but when I test the component I use it like this

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CompanyContactOverlayComponent],
      providers: [MyOverlayRef]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```

It throws me an error `Can't resolve all parameters for MyOverlayRef: (?, ?, ?)`. Saw many questions like this but can't find any answer.

My hunch is that since it's not an `@injectable`, I cannot use it in `provider[]`.

Any way I can create an instance of it automatically and fix this Issue.

**Edit**
In the service class, I'm creating a custom Injector to be Injected to `ref-class`

```
open<R = any, T = any>(
    content: string | TemplateRef<any> | Type<any>,
    data: T
  ): MyOverlayRef<R> {
    const configs = new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: true,
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
    });

    const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(configs);

    const myOverlayRef = new MyOverlayRef<R, T>(overlayRef, content, data);

    const injector = this.createInjector(myOverlayRef, this.injector);

    overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(OverlayModalComponent, null, injector));

    return myOverlayRef;
  }

  createInjector(ref: MyOverlayRef, inj: Injector) {
    const injectorTokens = new WeakMap([[MyOverlayRef, ref]]);
    return new PortalInjector(inj, injectorTokens);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try providing a mock value for it.

```
const mockOverlayRef = {}; // add the properties that are required, here it is an empty object

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CompanyContactOverlayComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: MyOverlayref, useValue: mockOverlayRef }] // mock it like so.
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```